# Html: JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I run html and javascript code but only html code run.Java script code is not work in my browser(chrome)

```js
var userName = prompt("What is your first name");
var lastName = prompt("What is your last name");
var age = prompt("What is your age");
alert("hello", +username + , "", +lastname);
```

```html
<p>This is second page welcome</p>
```

Comment: Is the `my.js` file in the same folder as the html?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your JavaScript. Here's what you had:

```js
var userName = prompt("What is your first name");
var lastName = prompt("What is your last name");
var age = prompt("What is your age");
alert("hello", +username + , "", +lastname);
```

The problems are on line 4:

1. String concatenation only requires `+` to join text together. The commas are resulting in a syntax error, so remove them.
2. Your variables are `userName` and `lastName`, not `username` and `lastname`. JavaScript variables are case-sensitive.
3. This won't throw an error, but if you wish to include spaces between each variable in your output (which it looks like you were trying to do), you need to type a space within the quotation marks. For example, `userName + "" + lastName` will result in `JohnDoe`, but `userName + " " + lastName` will result in `John Doe`.

Here's a working version with these issues corrected:

```js
var userName = prompt("What is your first name");
var lastName = prompt("What is your last name");
var age = prompt("What is your age");
alert("hello " + userName + " " + lastName);
```